# IllegalStateException when grouping by yearWeek or week

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, querydsl

I have a QueryDSL JPAQuery that is supposed to group by calendar week. I get an exception when calling list(...) on it. As long as I replace all occurences of yearWeek() by year() it works fine.

The java code:

```
QCrmContact qCrmContact = QCrmContact.crmContact;
BooleanExpression whereClause = qCrmContact.beUserId.eq(beUserId).and(qCrmContact.crmContactTypeId.in(contactTypeIds));

JPAQuery query = new JPAQuery(entityManager);

query.from(qCrmContact).where(whereClause).orderBy(qCrmContact.createdDatetime.yearWeek().asc())
     .groupBy(qCrmContact.createdDatetime.yearWeek(), qCrmContact.crmContactTypeId);
List<Tuple> rows = query.list(qCrmContact.createdDatetime.yearWeek(), qCrmContact.crmContactTypeId, qCrmContact.companyId.countDistinct());
```

The Exception:

```
Exception occurred during processing request: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.MethodNode
 +-[METHOD_CALL] MethodNode: '('
 |  +-[METHOD_NAME] IdentNode: 'yearweek' {originalText=yearweek}
 |  \-[EXPR_LIST] SqlNode: 'exprList'
 |     \-[DOT] DotNode: 'crmcontact0_.CREATED_DATETIME' {propertyName=createdDatetime,dereferenceType=ALL,propertyPath=createdDatetime,path=crmContact.createdDatetime,tableAlias=crmcontact0_,className=de.xxx.cxlbackend.database.model.CrmContact,classAlias=crmContact}
 |        +-[ALIAS_REF] IdentNode: 'crmcontact0_.ID' {alias=crmContact, className=de.xxx.cxlbackend.database.model.CrmContact, tableAlias=crmcontact0_}
 |        \-[IDENT] IdentNode: 'createdDatetime' {originalText=createdDatetime}

java.lang.IllegalStateException: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.MethodNode
 +-[METHOD_CALL] MethodNode: '('
 |  +-[METHOD_NAME] IdentNode: 'yearweek' {originalText=yearweek}
 |  \-[EXPR_LIST] SqlNode: 'exprList'
 |     \-[DOT] DotNode: 'crmcontact0_.CREATED_DATETIME' {propertyName=createdDatetime,dereferenceType=ALL,propertyPath=createdDatetime,path=crmContact.createdDatetime,tableAlias=crmcontact0_,className=de.xxx.cxlbackend.database.model.CrmContact,classAlias=crmContact}
 |        +-[ALIAS_REF] IdentNode: 'crmcontact0_.ID' {alias=crmContact, className=de.xxx.cxlbackend.database.model.CrmContact, tableAlias=crmcontact0_}
 |        \-[IDENT] IdentNode: 'createdDatetime' {originalText=createdDatetime}
```

It would be fine for me to use some hack and pass the native SQL to Oracle:

```
to_char(CREATED_DATETIME, 'IW.YYYY')
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by replacing

```
qCrmContact.createdDatetime.yearWeek()
```

with

```
StringExpression createdWeekYear = StringTemplate.create("to_char(CREATED_DATETIME, 'IW.YYYY')");
```